# Non-transitive relations defined on sets of cardinality 2

Tags: relations

When thinking about transitive relations, I came up with this "theorem":

> All relations $\mathrm{R}: S\to S$ defined on $S = \left\{1, 2\right\}$ are transitive.

But, I couldn't come up with a proof. So, can somebody help me and either prove the above or provide a counter-example for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider $R=\{(1,2), \, (2,1)\}$.
Then we have $1\,R\,2\,R\,1$ but not $1\,R\,1$.

Comment: what about non-symmetric, non-transitive relations? are there any of those?

Comment: Since besides this only $R\cup\{(1,1)\}$ and $R\cup\{(2,2)\}$ are the non-transitive relations which are symmetric, we can state that every relation on $S$ is either symmetric or transitive.

Comment: Apart from the ‘empty’ relation $\mathrm{R}=\emptyset$ (I don’t think we count that as symmetric but I’m not 100% sure actually)

Comment: The empty relation vacouosly satisfies $aRb\implies bRa$.

Comment: @Berci Thnx for all the help.